# Should the on-topic page reflect questions about tools used with patents?

Tags: discussion, scope

Speaking in response to this question, [How often is Google Patents updated?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/10572/10011), and specifically Robert's comment on it, I'd like to see the help center updated to include that questions about specific tools are allowed.

Stack Overflow has a similar clause:

> software tools commonly used by programmers

And I can imagine something like that on here. We currently say:

> 1. **Prior art for a US patent application**, whether anyone knows of any that might exist, or whether something you’ve found would qualify
> 2. **US patent law** or the patent approval process
> 3. **Specific aspects or interpretations** of a particular patent claim

I suggest either the addition of a four section, or perhaps an amendment to the second, to make it read something like:

> 2. **US patent law**, the patent approval process, or tools commonly used in researching patents (Public Pair, Google Patents, etc.)

Or something to that effect. We could risk the infamous [tech support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) issue, but I don't really get the impression that most people who post off-topic things here read that page, and we can always adjust it later if there's a lot of misunderstanding.

---

To be clear, of course, this really isn't a big deal given the current status of Ask Patents: we don't get a ton of these types of questions, and few of us non-CMs who do our work to moderate day-to-day probably have already seen that post, will see this one, or won't see the [/help/on-topic](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page being updated. But it seems like a good idea, on principle.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a great idea. I think we should fully support these types of questions. Let's make it happen.